# Monitor Out of frequency when installing os from DVD

Tags: display, resolution

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on **my friend's PC which has CRT 14" LG monitor** but When it boots form DVD, I am getting following error:

[image: screen]

Also when Using option "Try Ubuntu", Getting same error!

Now How to solve it?

And how to change screen resolution permanently from Disk to install and work on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The test-based installer will ultimately still install the OS, but when the machine boots into the fresh system the "Out of Frequency" will still occur because the OS has not been informed of the capabilities of the screen at any stage of the install. The boot paramaters can feed it this information so it is prepared. The user can then upgrade the drivers for the graphics card and the correct resolution can then be set.

Answer (score 1):

When you boot to your Ubuntu LiveCD you can add optional boot parameters that make small modifications for precisely situations like this.

Boot to your CD and you will see an icon of a small "man figure" at the bottom - when you see him press any key on your keyboard. You will be given some options - your mouse should work.

See if any of the options allow you to choose a resolution. If not you will need to append your own option by typing it in:

Type this: `vga=791`

This will give you a 16-Bit 1024x768 resolution that should work on almost all modern graphics cards.